# Moving scrollable div downwards automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

html

```
<div id="speech"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="testt"></div>
```

css

```
/*speech bubble*/
.bubble {
position: relative;
width: auto;
height: 40px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
display: inline-block;
left: 17px;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 40px; 
max-width: 240px;
float: left;
clear: both;
}

.bubble:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
border-color: transparent #FFFFFF;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
left: -10px;
top: 10px;
}

#test, #testt {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
#speech {
height: 500px;
width: 200px;
float: right;
overflow-y: scroll;
background-color: #000;
}
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";
$("#test").click(function () {
    $("#speech").append('<p class="bubble">test223123</p>');
});
$("#testt").click(function () {
    $("#speech").append('<p class="bubble">test</p>');
});
});
```

When I click on "test" a few times, the speech bubbles that are appended into the speech div continues to go downwards but the scroll thing stays at the top.

How do i make it such that the scroll bar goes to the bottom whenever new speech bubbles are added?

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, just use the scrollTop function. Add this single line:

```
$('#speech').scrollTop($('#speech').height());
```

You're now simply appending your bubble. When the bubble is appended, you find the height of your div and you use this value to scroll down.

I have made a little [codepen](http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/PqLWOP) where you can view all the code.

Comment: Thanks really useful. However this only works until a certain point, any way to get around it?

Comment: Care to approve my answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: Yup thanks! I found away to get around the problem mentioned in my comment :)

Comment: Wow sorry, missed that. What's was the problem exactly? Why/when didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

do not use height, but scrollHeight

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   "use strict";
   $("#test").click(function () {
     $("#speech").append('<p class="bubble">test223123</p>').scrollTop($("#speech").prop("scrollHeight"));
   });
   $("#testt").click(function () {
     $("#speech").append('<p class="bubble">test</p>').scrollTop($("#speech").prop("scrollHeight"));
   });
});
```